# disable active state primeng menu item after closing a dialog window

Tags: angular, primeng

I Have a [Panel menu](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/panelmenu) with items.
when I click on parent item I should open a [dialog window](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dialog)

Here's the menu **content ts**

```
this.items = [
  {
    label: 'File',
    icon: 'fa-file-o',
    command: (event) => {
        this.showDialog(event)
    }
  }
];
```

and **HTML**:

```
<p-panelMenu [model]="items" [style]="{'width':'300px'}"></p-panelMenu>

<p-dialog header="HELLO" [(visible)]="display" modal="modal" [responsive]="true" [width]="350" [minWidth]="200" >
    <span>hi</span>

</p-dialog>
```

The problem is when I close that window the menu state staus active .

I would that when I close the dialog window the menu return to "unactive" state ( grey color and not blue )

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialogue) to better illustrate my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlighting to blue color is connected with `expanded` field on item you can manually set `expanded` to false after close dialog.

Comment: I set expanded to false when I close window , not working 
I have updated my stackblitz repo

Comment: In your case it's hard to detect on what item you clicked, of course, you can save index of clicked item in some variable or set `expanded` to false on all `this.items` see [second solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dialogue-doufcg)